# joining a multicast group in linux using a command line

Tags: linux, ip, multicast

I'm trying to join/define a multicast group in linux. Is there anyway to achieve this using a command line? I know it is possible to do so programmatically. But I would like to test my idea before programming.

P.S: a route to 244.0.0.0 has already been added and eth0 supports multicast

Comment: Note that multicast is from *224.0.0.0* to *239.255.255.255*. *244.0.0.0* is not included.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `ssmping`. Just specify a regular *unicast* address and it will try to join the fixed *multicast* address *232.43.211.234* by sending periodic membership reports.. Not that you have to keep this application running or your multicast membership will time out.

Comment: this seems to work on some linux systems, but it does not work on mine:

ssmping 172.20.35.2

If 'ssmping' is not a typo you can use command-not-found to lookup the package that contains it, like this:
    cnf ssmping

Comment: This message just means that `ssmping` is not installed on your system. Run `cnf ssmping` to see which package is required and install it.